# NAnt: cannot resolve to boolean value

Tags: if-statement, nant, type-conversion

```
<if test="${deployErrors} &gt; 0">
   <fail message="MSDeploy failed" />
</if>
```

`${deployErrors}` is populated from a regex capture group and either has a numeric value or empty string. How can I check if this is greater than 0 in a NAnt if block? Here's the error I'm getting if deploy errors contains '1'

> '1 > 0' is not a valid value for
>   attribute 'test' of .
>       Cannot resolve '1 > 0' to boolean value.
>           String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've not tried it, but I think you need the whole of your expression within the curly braces:

> `<if test="${deployErrors > 0}">`

[See also the second example in the documentation page.](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/tasks/if.html)

**Update from OP**:

This worked:

```
<if test="${deployErrors != ''}">
```

Comment: Thanks, that put me on the right track. I couldn't compare them because the deployErrors would convert to a number. However, comparing it to '' works.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to do something with the actual numeric value then you could do something like this:

```
<if test="${int::parse('0' + deployErrors) > 10}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Trystan's answer - to parse a string to a bool, for a string e.g. `true`, `false`

```
<if test="${bool::parse(isEnabled)}">
```

From http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/functions/bool.parse.html